# Need Help With Delegates in iOS

Tags: ios, delegates

I'm having a hard time getting my head around delegates.  I tried putting together a simple example to teach myself, but it's just not working.

My simple test has two classes.  ClassA and ClassB.  ClassA has the delegate definition.  As well as a button that calls a method (`-(void)buttonHasBeenPressed:(id)sender`) that contains the delegate method call (`-(void)buttonPressed`).  ClassB is set (I think) to listen to the ClassA delegate and when the `-(void)buttonHasBeenPressed:(id)sender` is called it writes out to the console.

Here's the AppDelegate:

**.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DelegateTestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**.m:**

```
#import "DelegateTestAppDelegate.h"
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation DelegateTestAppDelegate


@synthesize window=_window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:[classA view]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Here's ClassA:

**.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ClassADelegate <NSObject>;
-(void)buttonPressed;
@end

@interface ClassA : UIViewController {

    id <ClassADelegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain) id <ClassADelegate> delegate;

-(void)buttonHasBeenPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

**.m:**

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize delegate;

-(id)init {

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    return [self init];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHasBeenPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"hola" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame =CGRectMake(50, 200, 100, 20);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}


-(void)buttonHasBeenPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate buttonPressed];
    NSLog(@"button has been pressed");
}


@end
```

Here's ClassB:

**.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ClassA.h"


@interface ClassB : UIViewController <ClassADelegate> {

}

@end
```

**.m:**

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassB

-(id)init {


    return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    return [self init];
}


-(void)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"delegating!");
}

@end
```

The expected result is to have both "button has been pressed" and "delegating!" written to the console when clicking on the "hola" button.

Thanks for your help...
Shawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your ClassB's instance? I can't find it in your posted code.
Also, where do you set the instance into ClassA as its delegate at? I can't find it neither.

If you are not doing this two things, your delegate will never be invoked.

Comment: OK... I think I understand your first question.  If I simply create the object from ClassB in the AppDelegate (just being lazy), that would take care of your first question.  As for your second question, I don't quite understand.  Thanks for your patience.  Feeling pretty dense right now...may need some sleep.

Comment: You should set your ClassB's instance to ClassA like this `classA.delegate = classB;` otherwise your classA.delegate is always nil, and won't be able to send out any methods. Right? :)

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to set **delegate** to class which conforms to **ClassADelegate** protocol, here which should be an object of **ClassB**